# check difference via minus between two file

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have two files `test1` and `test2`

test1

```
foo
bar
hello
world
```

test2

```
bar
world
hello
```

and I really want to obtain `foo` here, could anybody help me?  please ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To print all the lines in test1 which are not also in test2, run:

```
$ grep -vFf test2 test1
foo
```

#### How it works

The options to grep have the following meanings:

- `-v`

  Print only lines that do **not** match any of the patterns.
- `-F`

  Interpret the patterns as fixed strings, not regex.
- `-f test2`

  Read the patterns from test2.

Answer (score 0):

if not GNU grep

```
cat test1 test2 test2 | sort | uniq -u
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have vim installed, you can use :

```
vimdiff test1 test2
```

But it's just to edit files. If you only just want foo appears on the screen it's not what you want